# Convert Uppercase to lowercase rather than in starting of a word in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a string of full capitalized. I only want the first letter of a word in uppercase other in lower case. for eg: ALREADY BILLED TO COMPANY PLAN.
I want it as 'Already Billed To Company Plan'. How to convert it in Reactjs?
But actually the string is in an array which more string. I want to convert each string in that array.

Comment: it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956942/is-there-a-js-equivalent-to-css-text-transform-capitalize

Answer (score 3):

You can use css for it using this

```
.your-class {
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

or if you want pure ReactJS styling you can use this

```
<div style={{ textTransform: 'capitalize' }}> Your text </div>
```

Working sample

```css
.capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="capitalize"> this text should be capitalized using css </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well aside from splitting the string by spaces and then finding the first character of each substring and using `.toUpperCase` to ensure it is uppercase and then converting the rest of the string using `.toLowerCase`, you could consider putting the text in a class and apply `text-transform: uppercase;` to the CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS, just wrap your element in span and add  a class of `text-transform: capatilize`

for eg

```
<span className='capatilize'>
{
your content
}
</span>
```

But if you want to use in js only then [this question and its answer may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956942/is-there-a-js-equivalent-to-css-text-transform-capitalize)

Basically use create one function and in that function, with the help of regular expression, you can convert into capitalizing.